# Python play gif images and mp3 files at the same time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mp3, gif

I'm trying to improve my raspberry pi soundboard (build with Python) to include online .gif files after 'activating' a sound. What is the best approach to this?

I've tried PyGame, but that has trouble displaying .gif files. Is there a library or easier implementation to combine playing gifs and mp3 files?

Comment: What are you using right now?

Comment: this may help https://inventwithpython.com/chapter19.html